# using django with MSAL, how to get user info + find the methods to interact with microsoft graph

Tags: web

## Unable to retrieve user data using MSAL method.

Hi friends,

I am learning/creating a django project with microsoft authentication and the idea is that users from the tenant can perform actions inside the webapp. Thus, it requires sign in, retrieve user info, and interact with microsoft graph API.

I have downloaded the django with MSAL sample code from microsoft github, and able to run. My next step is retrieve user info and  other actions on microsoft graph API, mail for instance.  But, I try to get user info by using the access token.  but the following error shown:

```
 AttributeError at /home'IdentityWebPython' object has no attribute 'acquire_user_info'
```

Below is the view of the django project:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
import requests

ms_identity_web = settings.MS_IDENTITY_WEB

def index(request):
    return render(request, "auth/status.html")

@ms_identity_web.login_required
def token_details(request):
    return render(request, 'auth/token.html')

@ms_identity_web.login_required
def call_ms_graph(request):
    ms_identity_web.acquire_token_silently()
    graph = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
    authZ = f'Bearer {ms_identity_web.id_data._access_token}'
    results = requests.get(graph, headers={'Authorization': authZ}).json()

    # trim the results down to 5 and format them.
    if 'value' in results:
        results ['num_results'] = len(results['value'])
        results['value'] = results['value'][:5]

    return render(request, 'auth/call-graph.html', context=dict(results=results))

def home(request):

    # Acquire a token for the current user.
    token = ms_identity_web.acquire_token_silently(scopes=["user.read"])

    # Get the user's information.
    user_info = ms_identity_web.acquire_user_info(token)

    # Render the home page with the user's information.
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'user_info': user_info})

I
```

have try to look through MSAL documentation,
[https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache](https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)
, but I don't  think I understand.

Could anyone help how to fix the error and what are the right methods/where to look for the list of methods in MSAL python library so that I can retrieve user info and also interact with graph API.

THANKS!

This is my project idea/purpose:

1. Authenticate user using microsoft work account.
2. Once sign in, the page will display user information like name, email, job title, etc which retrieved from profile of their microsoft account

   1. A form where user can submit information/documents and stored in mysql database and once submition complete, confirmation email will be sent to respective user who is signing in.

Comment: You should post full stacktrace of your error.